localization of polynomial rings over integral domains
I am reading the section about localizations in Dummit&Foote's Abstract Algebra, and having some doubts on a proposition.

Let $S$ be an integral domain with fraction field $F$ and let $A$ be a nonzero ideal in $S[x]$. Suppose $AF[x]=(h(x))$ where $h(x)$ is a polynomial in $S[x]$ with leading coefficient $a\in S$. Let $S_a$ be the localization of $S$ with respect to the powers of $a$. Then
(1) $AF[x]\cap S[x]=AS_a[x]\cap S[x]$​, ...
Proof: We first show that $AF[x]\cap S_a[x]=AS_a[x]$. Since $S_a\subseteq F$, the containment $AS_a[x]\subseteq AF[x]\cap S_a[x]$ is immediate. Suppose that $f(x)\in AF[x]\cap S_a[x]$. If the leading term of $f(x)$ is $sx^N$ and the leading term of $h(x)$ is $ax^m$, then since $AF[x] = (h(x))$ we have $N\geq m$. Then the polynomial $f(x) - (s/a)x^{N-m}h(x)$ is again in $AF[x]\cap S_a[x]$ and is of lower degree than $f(x)$. Iterating, we see that $f(x)$ can be written as a polynomial in $S_a[x]$ times $h(x)$, so $f(x)\in AS_a[x]$. .....

To make things clear, let $D_S=S\setminus\{0\}$ and $D_a=\{\,a^n\,|\,n\geqslant0\,\}$. Then $F=D_S^{-1}S$ and $S_a=D_a^{-1}S$. So $\langle h(x)\rangle_{F[x]}=h(x)F[x]=AF[x]=D_S^{-1}A$ and $AS_a[x]=D_a^{-1}A$.
But I could not see how to obtain $f(x)\in AS_a[x]$ by "$f(x)$ can be written as a polynomial in $S_a[x]$ times $h(x)$". One way to reach this is to show that $h(x)\in AS_a[x]$ but I have no idea about it.
